# devise - encrypt the login email

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Do you know if Devise is providing a feature to store the email hashed in the database?

If this is the case, what are the drawback using this feature?

The two I can think of are:

- will not be obviously possible to see the email on the edit "screen" (except the [theoretical] case where the email would be stored using symmetric encryption instead of the standard one).
- if the salt is (for any reason) compromised and need to be changed, plan a recovery strategy would be a tough job (rather than just force the users to change the password at the next login). However, I think this is doable.

thanks,

Comment: I am searching for the same thing. Our client wants pretty much everything encrypted, but using attr_encrypted on the email login breaks Devise. Let me know if you solve your problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite answering the question, but I want to raise the point that you don't want to hash the login value.  Symmetric encryption, maybe.  Salted? No.

Why not?  Your login system has to find the correct record for the person who is trying to log in.  This means you have to hash/encrypt the value and compare with other hashed/encrypted values.  A salt would kill chances of doing that in one go, and you'd have to run a table scan each time.  Also, you would have nothing but probability to guarantee that two people's logins don't have a hash collision.

Using a single salt for the entire application kills the whole purpose of a salt, so there is no reason for using one.  However, if you wish to do so, then it solves the comparison problem.

But you are still left with the problem that you can have collisions.  The probability is low but nonzero, and as you get more users the Birthday Effect will come into play and you very well might get a problem.

Comment: It does not change much no compared to the normal case no? In place of passing around the plain email, you receive it, hash it and then pass around. It is all depending what is your hash salt. If the salt is common to the application, marco@example.com will have always the same hashed results (therefore two people will not possible signup with the same e-mail address). In the authentication mechanism, I (would) just validate that the hashed e-mail and password are good (=> the user is valid).

Comment: the birthday problem is hardly an issue. the cardinality is only 365(+1). with a 256 bit hash, the cardinality is 2^128. but anyway, it makes no sense to encrypt the id in a id/password authentication scheme. if the concern is to hide the email in case the storage is compromised, simply don't use the email as the id for authentication.

Comment: @pduey mmm you're right, to get .1% chance of collisions you'd need 10^36 users.